# как добавить Bottom bar в CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-layout, bottom-navigation-view, coordinator-layout

Я пытаюсь сделать экран, в котором есть `Bottom Bar`, но чтобы он не загораживал содержимое `RecyclerView`.
Вот код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/cl"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Mhap.AppBarOverlay">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/title" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/content_scrolling"
    android:layout_height="213dp" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="235dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="end|bottom"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="#80FFFF8D"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/include"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/naoftr"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="200dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text=" very very very very long track name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.100000024" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/naoftr"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.9" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/scp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/plpa"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_rew" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/plpa"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/scf"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/scf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_ff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/allt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Как видно на картинке `Bottom bar` загораживает содержимое `RecyclerView`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar - это то, что вы хотите?

Answer (score 0):

Так как в CoordinatorLayout нельзя указать что элементы будут зависемы друг от друга, вам нужно создать новый Layout, и поместить туда ваш RecyclerView и BottomBar. А Layout уже поместить в ваш CordinatorLayout.

Например вы будите использовать LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        .../>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        .../>
</LinearLayout>
```